# Truly RESTful service live example

Tags: rest, hateoas, hypermedia

Is there any real-life web service which is really 100% RESTful in terms of Fielding's thesis (Content negotiation, Hypermedia etc). I want to get a better grasp of REST and need something I could use from an automated client like Restfulie. Everything claimed to be RESTful I've come across so far seems to be either RPC or HTTP CRUD in fact.

Answer (score 4):

[Huddle](http://code.google.com/p/huddle-apis/).   It's not a free service but the docs explain how it works and it is one of the best publicly visible examples around.

Comment: The API looks great, just like in the big books. Too bad, it's not free, will see if they allow me to play with it in the trial period.